# Unity-based application crashes on iPad 1 when memory exceeds 40MB

Tags: ipad, memory, crash, unity-game-engine

I know this might be fairly Unity-specific, but the reason I am asking it here is because this is more of a general question regarding iPads and memory usage...

We have a Unity3D game project (not created by me, but I'm trying to help work out why it is crashing). It contains approximately 8 textures loaded at any one time, all 512x512 in size. There are probably no more than about 10,000 polygons on the screen in-game.

When we run it through Instruments on an iPad 2, it peaks at around 60 MB, which seems like it's well within the memory capabilities of that machine. However, when we try to run it on an iPad 1, even after a reboot to clear memory, Instruments shows it get to about 40 MB of loading before it crashes.

Would there be any reason why the iPad 1 cannot cope with more than 40 MB? I am aware the iPad 1 only has 256 MB compared with the iPad 2's 512 MB, but surely this is still well within the device's capabilities?

EDIT: The iPad 1 is running iOS 4.2.1 and the iPad 2 is running iOS 5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know the iOS version installed on the iPad 1 and it can variate the base memory used by the OS.

With my experience, a 40MB limit is in line with the 30-50MB range I'm used to see on Apple devices with just 256MB of RAM, before the memory warning is called.

Comment: That's useful to know, thanks. The iPad 1 is running iOS 4.2.1. What surprises me is that, compared with a lot of full-on iOS games, we're not doing an awful lot in ours. We have thought of using a texture atlas, but that will be a lot of work. Do you think it's worth trying?

Comment: For me you can consider to not support the iPad 1: compared to the iPad 2 and the new iPad, its CPU/GPU is very bad!

Comment: But you can't do that, can you? I heard it wasn't possible to limit unless you check for specific hardware, e.g. front-facing camera... And then Apple probably won't allow that unless we actually use the front-facing camera.

Comment: You can add the limit you want and use different hardware requirements to exclude particular devices. You don't need to actually use the camera to require it.

Comment: Is it really okay just to use UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities then? I read somewhere else on here that using it for hardware that you're not using will get your app rejected (can't find the link now). Is this not true?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to toss out iPad1 support to get your app working. The way you can avoid this problem is to decompress the textures and then write each one to a file. Then, memory map each file and use the memory mapped address instead of the normal memory address. An iOS device can map about 700 megs of data from a file in this way and you can send the memory to the graphics card in the normal opengl way.